# Display error messages containing variables when validating forms in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

I have the $validate variable in my model which contains:

```
var $validate=array(
```

"username" => array(
   "usernameValid" => array(
     "rule" => "__alphaNumericDashUnderscore",
     "message" => "The username you entered is not valid!"
   )
  )
 );

The question is: how do I return an error message from the `__alphaNumericDashUnderscore()` validation method and throw it in the `message` key in the rules array?

For example, this method, `__alphaNumericDashUnderscore()`, returns true or false, depending on the user input contains forbidden characters. But what if in this method, I would like to return which specific forbidden characters the user has typed and display them together with the `messages`? Something like `"The username you entered is not valid! You have used the following forbidden characters: $chars"`.

Do you have any idea of how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, CakePHP validation method only return True or False. But it is still PHP. You can do anything. Here is my hack :

```
<?php
class User extends Model {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $invalidChars = "";
    var $validate=array("username" => array( "usernameValid" => array( 
        "rule" => "__alphaNumericDashUnderscore", 
        "message" => "The username you entered is not valid! You have used the following forbidden characters: $this->invalidChars" 
    )));

    function alphaNumericDashUnderscore($check) {
        // Process the value
        // Assign invalid char, $this->invalidChars = $chars
        // Return true or false
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I haven't come across this solution. It's what I've been looking for, thanks again!